# What is the main conflict/problem in "Sleepy Hollow" (1999)?

Tags: sleepy-hollow

Could anyone, kindly, tell me the main conflict in the movie "Sleepy Hollow" from 1999? I've watched the film, but I'm having difficulty in trying to determine exactly what the main conflict is.

Please enlighten me on this. I'd appreciate your response.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you're after when asking for the *"main conflict"* of the movie. Are you asking for a plot-explanation or something else?

Answer (score 4):

It's a loose adaptation of the 1820's short story "[Legend of Sleepy Hollow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Sleepy_Hollow)", in which a headless horseman (implied that it is a local, Brom Bones) scares away (and possibly kills) a rival suitor (Ichabod Crane) for a girls hand.

In the case of [the movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleepy_Hollow_%28film%29), the Headless Horseman is an actual supernatural being, which is being controlled and sent out do to murder, which Johnny Depp (portraying Ichabod Crane as a detective) arrives to investigate. The movie is basically a murder mystery with a supernatural killer.